# The tag 'Ribbon' does not exist in XML namespace

Tags: c#, wpf, ribbon

I am trying to develop a WPF Application with Ribbon Control on .Net 4.5 Framework.
As far as I know, [MSDN Ribbon Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.ribbon.ribbon%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is now included in the Net 4.5 framework, therefore, I don't need to add [this](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11877) anymore.

But when I try to add this code :

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel>
        <Ribbon>
        </Ribbon>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

I got the following error. Am I missing something?

```
The tag 'Ribbon' does not exist in XML namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'.
```

EDIT :

```
using System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon;
```

also does not work.

```
The type or namespace name 'Ribbon' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows.Controls' (are you missing an assembly reference?)  c:\tmp\tst2\tst2\MainWindow.xaml.cs
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a reference to System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon.dll (which is part of the .NET 4.5 framework. Then you need to add the namespace to your XAML, something like:

```
xmlns:ribbon="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon"
```

to your window to get the namespace, then you can use it like

```
<ribbon:Ribbon ... />
```

like Cole Johnson said.

Here's the [MSDN reference on the Ribbon class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.ribbon.ribbon%28v=vs.110%29), which shows all this information.

Comment: `xmlns:ribbon="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon"` throws the Error 1 The type or namespace name 'Ribbon' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows.Controls' (are you missing an assembly reference?) C:\tmp\tst2\tst2\obj\Debug\MainWindow.g.cs 18 31 tst2
 error. It is too weird.

Comment: Well, if you're using .NET 4.5, it certainly is there: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.ribbon.ribbon(v=vs.110) - are you referencing the System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon DLL?

Comment: I was thinking that I didn't need to reference to DLL because it was part of the framework. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It is <ribbon:Ribbon />

Also you need to reference the scheme of the ribbon

Comment: I checked that `using System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon;` also does not work.

Comment: @noway that's how you reference it in your C# code. But you need to access it in XAML. So you need to add the namespace.